# Maintain reference to this in jQuery

Tags: jquery, bind, this, live

I'm converting a bunch of hyperlinks to make simple GET requests using jQuery. I want to maintain the reference to `this` within the Ajax call, do i need to be using `bind`/`live`/something else?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mylink").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url,function(data){
            $(this).parent().html(data); // this is now out of scope
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".moderate").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $this.attr('href');

        $.get(url,function(data){
            $this.parent().html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".moderate").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var that = $(this);
        $.get(url,function(data){
            that.parent().html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: note that `this` (and thus `that`) is a DOM node, and `parent()` is a jQuery function. you'd need to do `$(that).parent()`

Comment: that needs to be assigned `$(this)` and not `this`, otherwise you can't call `parent()` on it as it won't be a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save `this` to another variable, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mylink").click(function(){
        var realThis = this;
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url,function(data){
            $(realThis).parent().html(data); // realThis is now in scope
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The AJAX callback can access the variables of the outer method, so this technique works fine.

You only need to call `live` if you want to handle *all* `.mylink` elements, even ones that were added later.

Answer (score 1):

Scoping is a mess in javascript :)

In jQuery 1.4, you have a built-in proxy function that can bring the scope into any callback, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/.

But it's quite easy to create one yourself:

```
var proxy = function( fn, scope ) {
    if ( typeof fn !== 'function' ) {
        return function() {};
    }
    scope = scope || this;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply( scope, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".moderate").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, proxy(function(data) {
            $(this).parent().html(data);
        }, this));
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can also put the scope in a variable and access it later:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".moderate").click(function(){
        var scope = this;
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $(scope).parent().html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The general understanding of scoping in Javascript is a mess, not JavaScript scoping per se :)